# Access a row from a df based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I am trying to find out the rows where the reliability is <0.70, but the output seems to include rows where Reliability is 0.70 as well. What could be wrong?

---

Original DF:

---

po_id   po_name product year measure rate denominator numerator is_reported reliability

---

0   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  18  CHLAMSCR    67.740000   62.0    42.0    True    NaN
1   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  19  AMROV64 80.000000   20.0    16.0    True    NaN
2   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  19  CISCOMBO10  17.650000   34.0    6.0 True    NaN
3   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  19  OFCSTAFF    69.440000   NaN NaN True    0.76
4   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  18  BCS5274 86.420000   302.0   261.0   True    NaN
5   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  19  SPD1    57.810000   64.0    37.0    True    NaN
6   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  19  PDCS    79.530000   127.0   101.0   True    NaN
7   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  19  TCOC_250K_GEO_RISKADJ   289.281096  NaN NaN False   NaN
8   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  19  CBPD4   67.440000   129.0   87.0    True    NaN
9   1051408 Aberdeen Care Alliance  Commercial HMO/POS  18  COORDINATE3 55.370000   NaN NaN True    0.74

---

Code added to locate where reliability is less than 0.70
awards_test_df.loc[awards_test_df['reliability'] <0.70]

---

Output:

```
po_id   po_name product year    measure rate    denominator numerator is_reported   reliability

191 1008200 Advancements Physicians Medical Center  Commercial HMO/POS  18  ACCESS3 58.13   NaN NaN True    0.60
515 1021102 Baird Medical Group Commercial HMO/POS  18  COORDINATE3 60.02   NaN NaN True    0.70
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
8606    1038400 Vf Healthcare   Commercial HMO/POS  18  OFCSTAFF    68.78   NaN NaN True    0.70
8620    1038400 Vf Healthcare   Commercial HMO/POS  18  MDINTERACT3 79.57   NaN NaN True    0.70
8800    1006001 Viva Physicians Commercial HMO/POS  18  ACCESS3 66.25   NaN NaN True    0.70
8869    1017708 Waltz Hospital  Commercial HMO/POS  19  MDINTERACT3 81.01   NaN NaN True    0.70
9142    1028100 Zeke Medical Group  Commercial HMO/POS  18  ACCESS3 56.37   NaN NaN True    0.70
```

Comment: We would need to see some sample data, and your code

Comment: I think the value rounded to 2 decimal places may be 0.70 but the actual value may be < 0.70

Comment: I have updated the original question with the Data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just display formats.  Try below to check

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"reliability":np.random.uniform(.65,.75, 100)})

df = df.loc[df.reliability.lt(.7)].assign(twodp=df.reliability.round(2)).query("twodp.eq(.7)")
```

| reliability | twodp |
| --- | --- |
| 0.695661 | 0.7 |
| 0.699588 | 0.7 |
| 0.698993 | 0.7 |
| 0.697933 | 0.7 |
| 0.698356 | 0.7 |
| 0.699906 | 0.7 |
| 0.695279 | 0.7 |

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems perfectly fine when reproducing it:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [ { "po_id": 191, "po_name": 1008200, "product": "Advancements Physicians Medical Center  Commercial HMO/POS", "year": 18, "measure": "ACCESS3", "rate": 58.13, "denominator": "NaN", "numerator": "NaN", "is_reported": True, "reliability": 0.6 }, { "po_id": 515, "po_name": 1021102, "product": "Baird Medical Group Commercial HMO/POS", "year": 18, "measure": "COORDINATE3", "rate": 60.02, "denominator": "NaN", "numerator": "NaN", "is_reported": True, "reliability": 0.7 }, { "po_id": 8606, "po_name": 1038400, "product": "Vf Healthcare   Commercial HMO/POS", "year": 18, "measure": "OFCSTAFF", "rate": 68.78, "denominator": "NaN", "numerator": "NaN", "is_reported": True, "reliability": 0.7 }, { "po_id": 8620, "po_name": 1038400, "product": "Vf Healthcare   Commercial HMO/POS", "year": 18, "measure": "MDINTERACT3", "rate": 79.57, "denominator": "NaN", "numerator": "NaN", "is_reported": True, "reliability": 0.7 }, { "po_id": 8800, "po_name": 1006001, "product": "Viva Physicians Commercial HMO/POS", "year": 18, "measure": "ACCESS3", "rate": 66.25, "denominator": "NaN", "numerator": "NaN", "is_reported": True, "reliability": 0.7 }, { "po_id": 8869, "po_name": 1017708, "product": "Waltz Hospital  Commercial HMO/POS", "year": 19, "measure": "MDINTERACT3", "rate": 81.01, "denominator": "NaN", "numerator": "NaN", "is_reported": True, "reliability": 0.7 }, { "po_id": 9142, "po_name": 1028100, "product": "Zeke Medical Group  Commercial HMO/POS", "year": 18, "measure": "ACCESS3", "rate": 56.37, "denominator": "NaN", "numerator": "NaN", "is_reported": True, "reliability": 0.7 } ]
awards_test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
awards_test_df.loc[awards_test_df['reliability'] <0.70]
```

Output:

```
|    |   po_id |   po_name | product                                                    |   year | measure   |   rate |   denominator |   numerator | is_reported   |   reliability |
|---:|--------:|----------:|:-----------------------------------------------------------|-------:|:----------|-------:|--------------:|------------:|:--------------|--------------:|
|  0 |     191 |   1008200 | Advancements Physicians Medical Center  Commercial HMO/POS |     18 | ACCESS3   |  58.13 |           nan |         nan | True          |           0.6 |
```